# Are individual users counted more than once in the "Total Reputation" counts on the league pages?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I am trying to interpret the "Total Reputation" counts on the [StackOverflow leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow):

[image: Screenshot of total reputation counts]

Because the amounts in the Total Rep column end with '+', does that mean that users with high reputation get counted in each tier they qualify for, or just the highest one?

For example, does a user with 45k reputation get counted as (1+, 200+, 500+, 1000+, 2000+, 3000+, 5000+, 10000+, 25000+) or just (25000+)?

Comment: You can answer this yourself: look at the rank of the persons closest to 50k rep and 100k. Hint: it's about 230 and 68 resp.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Mat for the suggestion.  I was able to confirm that users ARE "double-counted" in this way.

To verify this, look at the individual users.  The users with at least 100k rep go until [#68 (jalf at the time of this post)](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31?sort=reputationchange&page=2).  The user in [position #69* (OMG Ponies)](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31?sort=reputationchange&page=2) has less than 100k (99,630).  So far, we've confirmed that the count of 68 for 100k users is correct.

- If users ARE being double-counted (i.e., the 230 users with 50k+ rep also includes the 68 users with 100k+ rep), then we would expect user #230 to be the last user with 50k or more reputation.
- If users are NOT being double-counted (i.e., there are 230 users with 50k+ rep, NOT including the 68 users with 100k+ rep), then the last user with 50k or more rep should be in position #298.

If we check the rankings, the user in position [#230 (chaos)](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31?sort=reputationchange&page=5) is in fact the last user with 50k+ rep (again, as of the time of this post).  [#231 (Pablo Santa Cruz)](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31?sort=reputationchange&page=5) has only 49,855.

So users are counted in **every** tier that they qualify for under Total Reputation counts.

<sub>* (snicker)</sub>

Comment: I can't claim my brain is able to follow this. Maybe because it is sunday. Blindly +1ing anyway!

Comment: Note that the leagues are updated only once a day, so the count being a couple of users off after the day is a couple of hours old is expected.

Comment: This is correct. A user with over 100k rep is counted in every bucket.